# What HTML class to use for a page title?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

My theme like most WP themes defaults the page title to an H1. However, my theme OceanWP allows me to change the heading tag to either H1-H6, div, span, or p.

I don't want my page title to be H1 as I want my H1 on my page body for SEO. So which do I choose?

Definitely not H1-H6 and from my understanding, not a div. So, span or p for page title?

[image: Image of the settings I am asking about in OceanWP]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<p> </p>` tag for page title. if you want any style simple to add a class like `<p class="your-class"> </p>`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I chose but thanks for confirming. I appreciate it.